# Handle "Invalid hex characters in escape" in tomcat level

Tags: rest, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

Am doing some system testing to URL Sanitation. So I tried rushing the APIs with junk data.Example

```
http://ipaddress/AppContext/api1?query=%S%n%n%s
```

If I call this API , my log throws an exception `'Invalid HEX character in escape sequence %n'`

How to I catch this in tomcat level and throw a `400 bad request`

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Tomcat doesn't decode the query string until the application requests one or more parameters. The best you can do is write a Filter that always tries to access the query string before the main request processing and returns a 400 response if an exception is thrown.